# Opportunities Component in Lightning for Outlook

Tags: lightning, opportunity, lightning-outlook

Quick question here that I can't seem to find an answer to online.

Is the Opportunities component on the Lightning for Outlook side-panel supposed to be sticky?

For example: When you open an email in Outlook, and the side-panel populates with the relevant records, should all associated Opportunities appear as well?

FYI: I have added the Opportunities Lightning Component to the "Standard Email Application Pane" which is the only active Lightning Application Pane

Any ideas as to why I must navigate through the Account/Contact to finally get to the Opportunity? Is this how it's supposed to work?

Answer (score 0):

It only shows up if the contact on the email has a "Contact role" on an opportunity.